# Compatibility issues of camera2 api in app

Tags: android, android-camera

I want to open camera in app itself and click pictures automatically when function is called. Camera2 api is not compatible with all devices. I need solution so that the camera should be compatible with all devices. If there is any library that can solve my problem or any other solution?

Comment: You can use camera api ( https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera )  if your target android api < 21

Answer (score 0):

[crammeur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3609883/crammeur) gives a good advice:

> You can use camera api ( [developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera) ) if your target android api < 21

But there is a bot more:

Actually, you can use the *deprecated* camera API regardless the target Android API. More than that, I recommend to use this old API for devices that has API >= 21, but feature a Legacy level of camera2 device.

But it is not good to rely on the backwards compatibility layer for devices with *native* camera2 support. The best practice is to have both solutions in your app, and choose the one that is best for specific device.

You can learn and reuse the code of some open-source libraries in your app, for example [CameraKit-Android](https://github.com/gogopop/CameraKit-Android) or [Fotoapparat](https://github.com/Fotoapparat/Fotoapparat).